# iOS 8 Storyboards : Exception on UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a problem with storyboards right now ... I don't know what happens but every time that I try to change scene I've got an exception :

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b05eae0`

What I did is just adding a bar button item to the navigation bar, Ctrl + drag to the controller I want to target and choose "Show". Any idea on what's going on ?

**EDIT :**

ToDoListTableViewController:

```
#import "ToDoListTableViewController.h"
#import "ToDoItem.h"
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface ToDoListTableViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end

@implementation ToDoListTableViewController


- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    // Retrieves view controller's data
    AddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];

    // Retreives the to-do item created and adds it if not null
    ToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Add a property to the class : a Mutable array that will contains the toDoItems
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Load initial random data to the toDo array
    [self loadInitialData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/**
 *  Loads initial data, random dumb one right now
 */
- (void)loadInitialData {
    ToDoItem *item1 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item1.itemName = @"First item";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];

    ToDoItem *item2 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item2.itemName = @"Second item";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item2];

    ToDoItem *item3 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item3.itemName = @"Third item";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item3];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

/**
 *  Sets the number of sections in table view
 */
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

/**
 *  Sets the number of rows in the table view
 */
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section (e.g number of items in array)
    return [self.toDoItems count];
}

/**
 *  Define the behavior of each cell in the table view.
 *  This is here that all graphical stuff must be done.
 */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;

    // Set the checkmark if the task had been completed or remove it
    if (toDoItem.completed) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

/**
 *  Delegate method : detects user's input on a table cell and acts accordingly
 */
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Do not select the cell tapped
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    // Detects which cell has been tapped
    ToDoItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Toggle completion of task
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;

    // Reload cell into table view
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

@end
```

AddToDoItemViewController:

```
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface AddToDoItemViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
- (IBAction)customEvent:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation AddToDoItemViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

/**
 *  Launched before changing view
 *  In this case, the "Save" button has been linked to the back segue
 */
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Do not do anything and leave the function if the button tapped is not the Save button
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;

    // If the field is not empty, we create a new to-do item and sets its text.
    // We also set its completion to "NO" (we don't want to have auto-completed tasks on creation)
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to show more code. Have you added a prepareForSegue function in your view controller? Error seems to imply that the "view" property is being requested from a segue object. Have you used the segue anywhere in your code?

Comment: I have edited my question to put some code, but I had no reference to this particular segue. I have the problem when I am in the table view controller when I want to add a to do item (click on "+" button).

Comment: Do you get the crash when unwinding to the "ToDo" or when showing "AddItem"?

Comment: @joakim : When showing "AddItem"

Comment: Do you have a backtrace from the debugger from when the exception occurs? If not, try adding an exception breakpoint and then rerunning your program. Posting the backtrace for the errant call to -[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate view] will help.